# C99 in Python module for Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-c-extension

I have a Python C module that is is written in C99. On Microsoft Windows, the C++ compiler used seems to be hard coded into Python, and on Python 2.7 this equals Visual C++ 9.0, which (although not *that* old, C99 is after all from 2000) seems to lack support for C99 for some curious reason (I guess MS were never much for standards...).

Is there a way to compile the Python module under Windows? For example, can I override the choice of compiler version, assuming for example that VS2017 is installed?